# Unusual requests to openshift website

Tags: python, django, httprequest, openshift

I don't know whether it's related, but I've deleted my OpenShift Django app which was pointed to from my own domain because it wasn't scalable and created a new one (same name and everything) which could scale. I uploaded the code back, restarted the app and configured the custom domain. Everything works like it was earlier, however, I am receiving requests which I can't identify:

```
- - - [19/Aug/2015:16:15:57 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 2569 "-" "-"
- - - [19/Aug/2015:16:15:59 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 2569 "-" "-"
- - - [19/Aug/2015:16:16:01 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 2569 "-" "-"
- - - [19/Aug/2015:16:16:03 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 2569 "-" "-"
- - - [19/Aug/2015:16:16:05 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 2569 "-" "-"
- - - [19/Aug/2015:16:16:07 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 2569 "-" "-"
- - - [19/Aug/2015:16:16:10 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 2569 "-" "-"
- - - [19/Aug/2015:16:16:12 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 2569 "-" "-"
- - - [19/Aug/2015:16:16:14 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 2569 "-" "-"
- - - [19/Aug/2015:16:16:16 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 2569 "-" "-"
- - - [19/Aug/2015:16:16:18 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 2569 "-" "-"
- - - [19/Aug/2015:16:16:20 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 2569 "-" "-"
- - - [19/Aug/2015:16:16:22 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 2569 "-" "-"
- - - [19/Aug/2015:16:16:24 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 2569 "-" "-"
- - - [19/Aug/2015:16:16:26 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 2569 "-" "-"
- - - [19/Aug/2015:16:16:28 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 2569 "-" "-"
```

Neither IP address nor user agent is specified. What (or less likely who) could this be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is HAProxy making sure that your application is running (since you are running a scaled application)